# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir correctamente usando un sort()?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, ordenamiento

Estoy haciendo un programa que me almacena participantes de una competencia y debo mostrarlos conforme a su numero de dorsal:

```
static String[] nom = new String[10]; //array para nombres
static int dor[] = new int[10]; //array para dorsales
```

Este es mi método de llenado de participantes:

```
static void inscribir(){
    int opi;
    System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de dorsal:");
    dor[i]=s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre del participante:");
    nom[i]=t.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrese mejor marca 2014:");
    mej2014[i]=s.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Ingrese mejor marca 2015:");
    mej2015[i]=s.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Ingrese mejor marca 2016:");
    mej2016[i]=s.nextFloat();
    i++;
    System.out.println("--------------");
    System.out.println("Una vez inscrito el participante, presione cualquier numero para regresar al menu. ");
    opi=s.nextInt();
    if(opi>=0){
        menu();
    }
}
```

Y muestro los datos con este otro metodo:

```
static void mostrarL(){
    Arrays.sort(dor);
    for(int x=0;x<=9;x++){
        System.out.println("Dorsal: "+dor[x]+" Nombre: "+nom[x]);
    }
}
```

Aquí se muestra el listado de resultados:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y, entiendo el por qué los valores me salen como null y 0. Los dorsales me salen ordenados pero los nombres me aparecen en la posición de *x* y no junto a sus respectivos dorsales. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al usar dos vectores diferentes no tienes la relación entre dorsal y nombre.

Te sugiero que uses arreglos multidimensionales.

```
 static String[][] nom_dor = new String[10][10];
```

O en su caso map

```
 static Map<Integer, String> = new HasMap<Integer,String>; // la clave sería dorsal y el valor sería el nombre
```

Comment: ¿Cómo puedo ordenar ese nuevo arreglo?

Comment: Hola @OscarAnibal hay varias formas de hacer lo que necesitas, a mi me gusta usar steams en java 8.    Si estas usando Map, la sintaxis sería Map<Integer, String> resultado = map.entrySet()
  .stream()
  .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
  .collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey, 
    Map.Entry::getValue, 
    (viejo, nuevo) -> viejo, LinkedHashMap::new));
Esteremos usando LinkedHashMap por que como bien sabes este devuelve el resultado según su insercción.   Tomado de la página https://ricardogeek.com/ordenar-un-hashmap-en-java/